# In Opensearch, How do I provide permissions for a specific user/role to save a vega visualization

Tags: opensearch, amazon-opensearch

A user building a visualization in AWS opensearch doesn't have the ability to save the visualization.

When attempting to save the visualization:

```
  {statusCode:403, error:'Forbidden'
  message : "no permissions for [indices:data/write/bulk] and User [name='someuser', 
     backend_roles=[], requestedTenant='MyTenant']: security_exception"
  }
```

We've created a custom role, mapped the user to the roll, and granted the roll both

```
  indices:data/write/bulk
  indices:data/write/bulk*
```

These index permissions are granted to both the query's target index pattern, and to the '*' index pattern. We've also verified that when the user is logged in the roll appears in the user's profile's "Roles and Identities".

What should I try next?

Comment: Same issue here. Querying on WebUI works, querying via CLI/API does not, because idk what parameter to provide to assume a role

Comment: @alanjds When querying via curl, I've always used curl with the "-u USER:PASS" option. 

E.g.

curl -s -u "$ESAUTH" -X POST -d "$ESBODY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "$ESURL"/SOME_INDEX_PATTERN-*/_search?size=1

Where $ESAUTH=myuser:mypassword, thereby granting the request permissions given to "myuser".

Comment: Yeah, I gone that route too. However, in my current company, I need to use the permissions _of the role_ that my user have access. My own user is powerless, but the roles it _can_ assume are powerful. But I found no way to "assume" the role on CLI calls.